# Write hyphen character in JTextpane until the line wraps

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I've written some text values inside the JTextPane , below to that contents I want to write hyphen character, so the contents will be look like Headings..

Currently I'm inserting hyphen to the count of that content length.

Comment: The problem you have there is that the width of the text area and rendering requirements of the text will always be different...

Comment: Looks like a cross post to me: http://www.coderanch.com/t/621518/GUI/java/Write-Jtextpane-wraps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need hyphenation in the JTextPane use [the article](http://java-sl.com/Hyphenation_In_JEditorPane.html) showing how it could be implemented.

From the description it could be that you need usual bullets with hyphen sign. If yes there is [another article](http://java-sl.com/bullets_numberings.html) shows how bullets could be achived.